# how to delay keypress enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
     onKeyDownHandler(event);
}, false);


function onKeyDownHandler(e)
{
    var focus_id = e.target.id;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 13: // enter
          if(focus_id == "Text1")
          {
            alert("function 1");
          }else if(focus_id == "Text2")
          {
            alert("function 2");
          }else if(focus_id == "Text3")
          {
            alert("function 3");
          }
          return;
    }
}
```

is there anyway i can delay or make sure user dont spam by clicking the enter , how do i set keypress delay on my enter button ? which is the best way set delay timer or remove EventListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a timeout on enter press, and on another enter press, overwrite that previous timeout with the new one. That means that if you for example press enter again before the first timeout has ended, that first timeout will be overwritten by a new one, so that you get a new x amount of time before the actual timeout is executed. This works until infinity.

Example:

```
var keyup_timeout;
var timeout_delay_in_ms = 500;

element.on('keyup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default enter press action.
    var enter_pressed;

    if (e.which === 13) {
        enter_pressed = true; // Just an example to illustrate what you could do.
    }

    if (enter_pressed) {
        clearTimeout(keyup_timeout); // Clear the previous timeout so that it won't be executed any more. It will be overwritten by a new one below.

        keyup_timeout = setTimeout(function() {

            // Perform your magic here.

        }, timeout_delay_in_ms);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery [throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/) plugin to only handle call your function when there is a pause in keyDown events.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the default action for a period of time after the last Enter keypress:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownHandler, false);
var lastEnter = null;
function onKeyDownHandler(e) {
    var focus_id = e.target.id;
    switch (e.which || e.keyCode) { // Note the e.which, for x-browser compat
        case 13:
            if (lastEnter && Date.now() - lastEnter < 5000) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            lastEnter = Date.now();

            // Enter key processing...
            break;
        // ...other keys...
    }
}
```

Or using jQuery (you've tagged your question `jquery`, but don't appear to be using jQuery in your code):

```
$(window).on("keydown", function(e) {
    onKeyDownHandler(e);
});
var lastEnter = null;
function onKeyDownHandler(e) {
    var focus_id = e.target.id;
    switch (e.which) { // jQuery normalizes this for you
        case 13:
            if (lastEnter && Date.now() - lastEnter < 5000) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            lastEnter = Date.now();

            // Enter key processing...
            break;
        // ...other keys...
    }
}
```

---

Side notes:

- Since the return value of an `addEventListener` callback is completely ignored and `addEventListener` calls the handler with just a single argument, if you're not using `this` within the handler (as you appear not to be), there's no need to wrap a function around `onKeyDownHandler`; just use it directly.
- Some browsers use `which` for the keycode, others use `keyCode`, which is why I used `e.which || e.keyCode` in the `switch`. JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator will use `e.which` if it's not falsey, `e.keyCode` otherwise.